# Is there a tool for checking what method from what package I am using in Java?

Tags: java, methods, dependencies

I have Java projects referencing methods from several external jars. I would like to have a list of all the methods, including the class and package, which I am using in my projects. I have tried JDepend, but it stops at package level. Is there other any other tool I could use?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tattletale may be of help http://www.jboss.org/tattletale

Comment: Thank you!! But is there anything that I could use in eclipse?

Comment: Also, the results are still at package level, no details about methods.

Answer (score 0):

With [JavaDepend](http://www.javadepend.com) you can execute the following CQL request:

SELECT TYPES WHERE IsDirectlyUsedBy "myproject"

SELECT METHODS WHERE IsDirectlyUsedBy "myproject"

SELECT FIELDS WHERE IsDirectlyUsedBy "myproject"

And with CQL there's many other possibilities to query code base like a database.